# CSS background blur on scroll

Tags: css, html, scroll, blur

I have fixed background image and upon scroll I want the image to go blur. I know how to do blur in css but do it at specific scroll position.

Here is an example:
https://medium.com/good-music/f160ba9e6c52

Any thoughts, examples, advice of snippets will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to do same as given link? Show as what you do so far.

Comment: http://codepen.io/jiserra/pen/JzKpx

Comment: @antindexer here is an example of the image blur.
http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur

Answer (score 6):

This codepen does exactly what you want. With browser support in mind it uses 2 images though instead of blur:

http://codepen.io/sota0805/pen/pqLcv

Answer (score 2):

You can blur the element relative to how far you've scrolled.

```js
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        
        var distanceScrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
    
        $('.element').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur('+distanceScrolled/60+'px)');
        
    });
```

Here I am using `scrollTop()` to get the amount of pixels the window has scrolled, and then I set the blur on the element to that number divided by 60, which is just an arbitrary number I chose to get the blur I wanted.

If you want to add the blur at a certain point, you can use an element on the DOM and the check it's position relative to the window.

```js
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        
        var elOffset = $('.element').scrollTop() - $(window).scrollTop();
    
        if(elOffset < 450) {
            $(this).addClass('blur');
        }
        
    });
```

If `.element` is less than 450px from the top of the window, the class `blur` will be added to it. Your blur class would look something like this:

```css
    .blur {
        -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    }
```

You'll probably want to use a transition with it. Don't forget the vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

On your website example ( https://medium.com/good-music/f160ba9e6c52) there is **no css "blur" effect**.

You can find one normal image: https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/1440/1*THFG10B56f4TQOebO1Zd_w.jpeg

And a blurred image: https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/1440/gradv/29/81/40/darken/45/blur/20/1*THFG10B56f4TQOebO1Zd_w.jpeg

After superposing those two images, you have to change the opacity of the first one, it's done!

Answer (score 0):

I have only mention the how you can get the position with the scrolling.

```
$('#divscroll').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
     var toTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
     //from this you can get the distance from the top 
     //then you can blur the image as you want with relevent to the position of ur image
});
```

For IE,Opera previous bind will not work, so you need to

```
 $('#divscroll').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
       var toTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
       //Handle your logic     
   });
```

Hope this might help.
Cheers.!