# Change image when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a bit new to coding. I have a div with a background image. I want to be able to change the image from its blurred version to a clearer version as I scroll down. My HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="intro">
<div class="blur" style="background-image: url(&quot;blurimage.png&quot;);"></div>
<div class="clear" style="opacity: 0.00666667; background-image: url(&quot;image.png&quot;);"></div> 
</div>
```

My CSS code is like this:

```
.intro{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;

}
.blur{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -10;
    background-color: #222; 
}
.clear{
    background-size: cover;}
```

I have tried using many javascript functions but no avail. Please guide me as to how can I do this by using a Javascript function.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background blur on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697004/css-background-blur-on-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you could try

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    // this code is executed each time the user scrolls
    var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    // scrollPosition is 0 at the top of the page
    // it contains how many pixels have been scrolled down
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: couldn't understand. Could you please elaborate a bit more with an example

Comment: The above code (at the comment) is executed everytime the user scrolls (up or down). The `scrollPosition` variable contains a value indicating how many pixels are scrolled from the very top of the website. Using this value you can swap the background image depending on the scroll position by hiding or showing one of the background images.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JS file (I assume you have jQuery included as well):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('body').scroll(function() {
        $('.intro .clear').animate({
            height: scrollPosition,
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Also add this to `.clear`:

```
.clear {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Also keep in mind that this code will work if you have your image on top of the page. Otherwise feel free to change `$(document).scrollTop()` with the actual selector of the parent element.

I would also recommend renaming the `clear` class with some other name, since if you decide to use CSS framework or plugin at later point, that class name might be reserved for clearfix styles.

Comment: can you please post a link to help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhcza5fm/1/)**

made a simple example with changing the `background-color` . this is for example purposes only because i can't use your images

also...you need only 1 div inside the `intro` and toggle classes on that `div` from `.blur` to `.clear` and vice-versa and use CSS to style those classes.

the idea is that  you have only one `div` w to which you change the `background` depending on the scroll

HTML :

```
<div class="intro">
     <div class="blur"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.intro{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;

}

.intro div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -10;

}
.blur{
    background-image: url("blurimage.png");
    background-color: red; 
}
.clearimg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:blue
    background-image: url("image.png");
}
```

JQ :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $(".intro div").addClass("clearimg")
        $(".intro div").removeClass("blur")
    }else{
        $(".intro div").addClass("blur")
        $(".intro div").removeClass("clearimg")
   }
});
```